# Django models.ForeignKey filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a 2 models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name...
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)

class Fighter(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, filter(type="A")
```

Can you filter the drop down list of the foreign key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/, specifically, the ForeignKey.limit_choices_to section.

Hope that helps you out.